# SQOOP export fails on java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I have created following table in MySQL under **school** database:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I have following data in HDFS in **/school/student.csv** file:

```
1,Kain,Redington,kredington0@state.tx.us
2,Monica,Eble,meble1@yale.edu
3,Becca,Stothart,bstothart2@reverbnation.com
4,Ethelred,Rawlison,erawlison3@forbes.com
5,Abbey,Gellier,agellier4@house.gov
6,Laurens,Shilliday,lshilliday5@over-blog.com
7,Omar,Pimblotte,opimblotte6@exblog.jp
8,Sidnee,Jakubovics,sjakubovics7@webmd.com
9,Turner,Lavies,tlavies8@exblog.jp
10,Steffane,Duley,sduley9@altervista.org
```

when I am running sqoop command as:

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school \
--username **** --password ********* \
--table student \
--export-dir /sqoop_data/school/ \
--input-fields-terminated-by ","
```

It is giving error as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: 'Redington'
    at student.__loadFromFields(student.java:335)
    at student.parse(student.java:268)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Redington"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at student.__loadFromFields(student.java:327)
    ... 12 more
```

PS: I have tried making id column as **bigint** but still no luck.

**I am using sqoop 1.4.6 and MySQL 8.0.22**

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: "Redington" does not look like a number to me.  It's a problem with usage of sqoop.

Comment: What is `student.java`?

Comment: @[OneCricketer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) sqoop uses map-reduce to perform tasks so student.java is created by it to export data from hdfs and bring in mysql.

Comment: I found this error too with --update-mode. Have you fixed this ?