# Can Sqoop update record on Oracle RDBMS table that have different column structure with Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I'm a Hadoop newcomer trying to export data from Hive to Oracle. Can Sqoop update data to Oracle table let say,

Oracle Table have column A,B,C,D,E

I stored data on Hive table as B,C,E

Can Sqoop export update(just update, not upsert) with B,C as update keys and update just the E column from Hive?

Comment: Sqoop is a retired Apache project. Do you have to use it?

Comment: Yes, I have to.

Answer (score 1):

Pls mention `--update-key Prim_key_col_in_table`. Pls note `--update-mode` default is `updateonly` so you dont have to mention anything.
You can also add `input-fields-terminated-by` command if you want to.

here is a sample command -

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx/mytable --username xxxxx --password xxxxx --table export_sqoop_mytable --update-key Prim_key_col_in_table --export-dir /user/ingenieroandresangel/datasets/mytable.txt -m 1
```

Comment: Found NumberFormatException like this thread, any solution ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014697/sqoop-export-fails-on-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string

Comment: check table definition in both hive and Oracle. Make sure they are matching.